# El objetp guitar lo retorna null

Tags: java

Si se cumplen todas las condiciones debe pasar un objeto guitarra con cada uno de los atributos, en el ejemplo que tengo ya lo probé y se cumplen todas las condiciones, con una sola que no se cumpla el objeto llega null, pero si se cumple debería retornar el objeto guitar con las propiedades llenas.

```
**Inventory.java** (retorna null a guitar, ese es el problema)

package guitars;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Inventory {

    private List guitars;

    public Inventory() {
        guitars = new LinkedList();
    }

    public void addGuitar(String serialNumber, double price,
            String builder, String model,
            String type, String backWood, String topWood) {
        Guitar guitar = new Guitar(serialNumber, price, builder,
                model, type, backWood, topWood);
        guitars.add(guitar);
    }

    public Guitar getGuitar(String serialNumber) {
        for (Iterator i = guitars.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            Guitar guitar = (Guitar) i.next();
            if (guitar.getSerialNumber().equals(serialNumber)) {
                return guitar;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Guitar search(Guitar searchGuitar) {
        Guitar guitar;
        guitar = null;
        for (Iterator i = guitars.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            guitar = (Guitar) i.next();
// Ignore serial number since that’s unique
// Ignore price since that’s unique

            String builder = searchGuitar.getBuilder();
            if ((builder != null) && (!builder.equals(""))) {
                if (!builder.matches(guitar.getBuilder())) {
                    guitar = null;
                    continue;
                }
            }

            String model = searchGuitar.getModel();
            if ((model != null) && (!model.equals(""))) {
                if (!model.matches(guitar.getModel())) {
                    guitar = null;
                    continue;
                }
            }    

            String type = searchGuitar.getType();
            if ((type != null) && (!type.equals(""))) {
                if (!type.matches(guitar.getType())) {
                    guitar = null;
                    continue;
                }
            }

            String backWood = searchGuitar.getBackWood();
            if ((backWood != null) && (!backWood.equals(""))) {
                if (!backWood.equalsIgnoreCase(guitar.getBackWood())) {
                    guitar = null;
                    continue;
                }
            }

            String topWood = searchGuitar.getTopWood();
            if ((topWood != null) && (!topWood.equals(""))) {
                if (!topWood.matches(guitar.getTopWood())) {
                    guitar = null;
                }
            }
        }
         return guitar;
    }
}

**Guitar.java**
package guitars;

public class Guitar {

    private String serialNumber, builder, model, type, backWood, topWood;
    private double price;

    public Guitar(String serialNumber, double price,
            String builder, String model, String type,
            String backWood, String topWood) {
        this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
        this.price = price;
        this.builder = builder;
        this.model = model;
        this.type = type;
        this.backWood = backWood;
        this.topWood = topWood;
    }

    public String getSerialNumber() {
        return serialNumber;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double newPrice) {
        this.price = newPrice;
    }

    public String getBuilder() {
        return builder;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getBackWood() {
        return backWood;
    }

    public String getTopWood() {
        return topWood;
    }
}

    **FindGuitarTester.java**

    package guitars;

    /**
     *
     * @author HENRY GARCIA
     */
    public class FindGuitarTester {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Set up Rick’s guitar inventory
            Inventory inventory = new Inventory();
            initializeInventory(inventory);
            Guitar whatErinLikes = new Guitar("", 0, "Builder-3", "Model-3",
                                              "Type-3", "BackWood-3", "TopWood-3");
            Guitar guitar = inventory.search(whatErinLikes);
            if (guitar != null) {
                System.out.println("Erin, you might like this " 
                + guitar.getBuilder() + " " + guitar.getModel() + " "
                + guitar.getType() + " guitar:\n " 
                + guitar.getBackWood() + " back and sides,\n " 
                + guitar.getTopWood() + " top. \nYou can have it for only $ " 
                + guitar.getPrice() + "!");
             } else {
               System.out.println("Sorry, Erin, we have nothing for you.");

             }

        }

    private static void initializeInventory(Inventory inventory) {
    // Add guitars to the inventory...

           inventory.addGuitar("V95693",1499.95, "Builder-2", "Model-2",
                                "Type-2", "BackWood-2", "TopWood-2");
           inventory.addGuitar("V95694",1490.19, "Builder-3", "Model-3",
                                "Type-3", "BackWood-3", "TopWood-3");
           inventory.addGuitar("V95693",1400.95, "Builder-4", "Model-4",
                                "Type-4", "BackWood-4", "TopWood-4");
           inventory.addGuitar("V95695",1600.95, "Builder-5", "Model-5",
                                "Type-5", "BackWood-5", "TopWood-5");
           inventory.addGuitar("V95696",1700.95, "Builder-6", "Model-6",
                                "Type-6", "BackWood-6", "TopWood-6");
           inventory.addGuitar("V95697",1800.15, "Builder-7", "Model-7",
                                "Type-3", "BackWood-7", "TopWood-7");

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un error de lógica. En el método *search* de *Inventory* **siempre** devuelves *null*. Si encuentras un objeto guitar que coincide con el tuyo lo debes devolver y lo que haces es seguir el bucle. Es decir que si el siguiente objeto no coincide ya te va a devolver *null*. Para que te funcione haz algo así:

```
public Guitar search(Guitar searchGuitar) {
        Guitar guitar;
        guitar = null;
        for (Iterator i = guitars.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            guitar = (Guitar) i.next();
// Ignore serial number since that’s unique
// Ignore price since that’s unique

            String builder = searchGuitar.getBuilder();
            if ((builder != null) && (!builder.equals(""))) {
                if (!builder.matches(guitar.getBuilder())) {
                    guitar = null;
                    continue;
                }
            }

            String model = searchGuitar.getModel();
            if ((model != null) && (!model.equals(""))) {
                if (!model.matches(guitar.getModel())) {
                    guitar = null;
                    continue;
                }
            }

            String type = searchGuitar.getType();
            if ((type != null) && (!type.equals(""))) {
                if (!type.matches(guitar.getType())) {
                    guitar = null;
                    continue;
                }
            }

            String backWood = searchGuitar.getBackWood();
            if ((backWood != null) && (!backWood.equals(""))) {
                if (!backWood.equalsIgnoreCase(guitar.getBackWood())) {
                    guitar = null;
                    continue;
                }
            }

            String topWood = searchGuitar.getTopWood();
            if ((topWood != null) && (!topWood.equals(""))) {
                if (!topWood.matches(guitar.getTopWood())) {
                    guitar = null;
                }
            }
            if (guitar != null) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return guitar;
    }
```

Al final del bucle debes salir si ya tienes un objeto que coincida.

Aun así te recomiendo que implementes un método *equals* en Guitar. Quedaría mejor, más legible...

Comment: Enche  el método equals podría ser todo el código que evalúa que ninguna propiedad sea null?